# Sencha Touch Ext.List disappearing behind a wrapped toolbar

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I have written an MVC Sencha Touch app to query a database via JSON and then return the list in an Ext.List

The idea here is to have an iPhone-style UINavigationController effect that slides in for the results list.

To achieve this I use an Ext.Panel that loads 2 cards, one is my query (Ext.Form) the other is the results wrapper Ext.Panel (I use the wrapper to display a toolbar at the top since Ext.List is not capable of this)

I use the forms filter to trigger a 'search" method in the wrapper that then loads an instance of my Ext.List.

This all works quite well, except the results list fills the whole screen, and therefore sits "behind" the wrappers toolbar instead of below it.
The results don't even display at all unless the Ext.List has fullscreen:true.

Any suggestions most welcome.

Comment: Well I solved this by using Ext.NestedList instead of Ext.List. make sure you use a TreeStore not a normal Store

Comment: Hi Brett, it depends where you are putting the list instance. If the list instance is child card of your wrapper and you make it the active item, it does not overlap the docked toolbar at the top.
If you solved your problem, answer your own question and accept it. This way people looking to help others can better see which questions are still open.